# how to validate django custom database fields?

Tags: python, django

I'm reading the django documentation on [how to create custom database fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-model-fields/). However, there is no mention of how fields are validated. I looked into the source code of existing fields, but I can't find validation logic there either.

How do django fields handle validation? Or they don't do it at all, and let the database exceptions propagate up the stack trace?

Comment: `default_validators` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#using-validators

Comment: how is that used in `model.Field` subclasses??  This seems to refer to forms only

Comment: You can see the steps of form validation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation). It calls `to_python`, `validate()`, `run_validators()` and `clean` methods on Field. You can override these fields, check the existing built-in fields for [examples](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L592)